# CodeSmith 6: Generating Database TYpes

Tags: sql-server, database, code-generation, codesmith

From a ColumnSchema object in CodeSmith 6, I need to be able to generate a SQL Server table definition.  I'm having trouble generating the types; I need to be able to generate the following types:

```
varchar(100)
varchar(MAX)
int
bit
etc...
```

But I can't find a property for this.  Is there something in codesmith to extract this?  I've been searching but can't find anything...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create these values by having your template inherit [SqlCodeTemplate](http://docs.codesmithtools.com/display/Generator/SqlCodeTemplate). Then you would just pass the ColumnSchema object to the GetSqlParameterStatement method which will return this type information.

I'd highly recommend taking a look at the Database\DbSnapShot\TableSchema.cst and StoredProcedures\StoredProcedures.cst templates as they both show insight / or do what you are looking for.

Thanks

-Blake Niemyjski